# SQL Server 2016 - There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting INSTALLSHAREDDIR

Tags: sql-server-2016

I am trying to install new instance on the server with already installed instance but short after running the setup.exe I am getting the error:

*SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
There was a failure to calculate the applicability of setting INSTALLSHAREDDIR.
Error code 0x85640002.*

Tried different installation sources (Standard, Enterprise, with/without SP2) but the result is still the same.

Also tried running the commandline installation with configuration file and providing /INSTALLSHAREDDIR parameter but no luck either.

Any ideas how can I fix this issue?

EDIT:
Tried after server restart and tried instance repair but the error is still the same

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to install a second instance on the same server? Usually it's recommended to keep each instance to its own server.

Comment: Totaly agree but it's the requirement from the customer.